# Custom date range parameter OR pre-defined date from drop down in SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I am developing a SSRS report in MSvs which allows 2 different date selections.

One option is to select a custom date range using the `StartDate` and `EndDate` parameters (allow `NULL` is selected).

The other option is to select from a pre-defined set of dates listed in a drop down which can also be `NULL` by selecting 'Select Custom'.

I have 2 data sets both of which are stored procedures in SQL server. One is my main dataset and the other is `CalendarRanges` where I have defined the pre-defined date ranges as follows:

- CurrentWeek
- PreviousWeek
- CurrentMonth
- Custom

I have fully stripped my code to provide an example.

Main data set stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE MainDataset
(
    @StartDate DATETIME, 
    @EndDate DATETIME 
) 
WITH RECOMPILE  
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @StartDateKey INT, @EndDateKey INT

SELECT
    @StartDateKey = MIN(DateKey),
    @StartDate = MIN(CalendarDate),
    @EndDateKey = MAX(DateKey),
    @EndDate = MAX(CalendarDate)

FROM
    Dim.Calendar
WHERE
    CalendarDate >= @StartDate
      AND CalendarDate <= @EndDate

;WITH Sales AS
(
    SELECT
        Sales.CurrencyKey,
        OrderId,
    FROM
        Fact.Sales
    WHERE   
        Sales.OrderDateKey = @StartDateKey
),

Payments AS
(
    SELECT
        Payments.PaymentCurrencyKey,
        PaymentID
    FROM    
        Payments
    WHERE
        AND Payment.DateKey >= @StartDateKey
        AND Payment.DateKey <= @EndDateKey
)
SELECT
    Sales.*,
    Payments.*,
    @StartDate AS 'StartDate',
    @EndDate AS 'EndDate'
FROM
    Sales
    LEFT JOIN Payments
        ON Payments.PaymentCurrencyKey = Sales.CurrencyKey
```

The Start and End Dates are linked with my `@StartDate` and `@EndDate` parameters in SSRS.

Dataset 2:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE CalendarRanges 
AS
SELECT 
1 AS [Order],
Value,
Label
FROM 
(SELECT 
CurrentWeekOfYear AS Value,
'CurrentWeek' AS Label
FROM Calendar
WHERE CalendarDate =  CONVERT(varchar, getdate(), 23)) CurrentWeek

UNION 

 -- Previous Week
SELECT 
2 AS [Order],
Value,
Label
FROM 
(SELECT 
  DISTINCT CurrentWeekOfYear -1 AS Value,
 'PreviousCurrentWeek' AS Label 
  FROM Calendar 
 WHERE CalendarDate =  CONVERT(varchar, getdate(), 23)) PreviousWeek

UNION

-- Current Month
SELECT 
  4 AS [Order],
  Value,
  Label
 FROM
 (SELECT 
 DISTINCT CurrentMonth AS Value,
 'CurrentMonth' AS Label
 FROM Calendar
 WHERE CurrentMonth = MONTH(GETDATE())) CurrentMonth

UNION

-- Custom 
 SELECT 
 5 AS [Order],
 value,
 Label
 FROM (
 SELECT 
 NULL AS Value,
'Select Custom' AS Label
 ) Custom
```

If I choose the 'Select Custom' option from the drop down and then select a custom start and end date the report runs as expected.

However, if i leave the custom start and end dates `NULL` and choose a pre-defined date from the drop down, the report returns no data. I have tested by pre-defining a date that displays data when selecting custom so I know that the data is there.

I would like to manipulate the report so that if the custom start and end date parameters are `NULL`, then use the drop down parameter instead but I am struggling to understand how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You can change some logic in your proecure...it may be help you out...

```
ALTER PROCEDURE MainDataset
(
    @StartDate VARCHAR(20)=NULL, 
    @EndDate VARCHAR(20)=NULL
) 
WITH RECOMPILE  
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @StartDateKey INT, @EndDateKey INT

SELECT
    @StartDateKey = MIN(DateKey),
    --@StartDate = MIN(CalendarDate),
    @EndDateKey = MAX(DateKey)
   -- @EndDate = MAX(CalendarDate)

FROM
    Dim.Calendar
WHERE

convert(DATETIME,CalendarDate)  
BETWEEN Convert(DATETIME,CASE WHEN isnull(@StartDate,'')='' THEN CalendarDate
ELSE isnull(@StartDate,'') END)                     
AND Convert(DATETIME, CASE WHEN isnull(@EndDate,'')='' THEN CalendarDate 
ELSE isnull(@EndDate,'') END)  

/* this Line is commented....
CalendarDate >= @StartDate
AND CalendarDate <= @EndDate
*/

;WITH Sales AS
(
    SELECT
        Sales.CurrencyKey,
        OrderId,
    FROM
        Fact.Sales
    WHERE   
        Sales.OrderDateKey = @StartDateKey
),

Payments AS
(
    SELECT
        Payments.PaymentCurrencyKey,
        PaymentID
    FROM    
        Payments
    WHERE
        AND Payment.DateKey >= @StartDateKey
        AND Payment.DateKey <= @EndDateKey
)
SELECT
    Sales.*,
    Payments.*,
    @StartDate AS 'StartDate',
    @EndDate AS 'EndDate'
FROM
    Sales
    LEFT JOIN Payments
        ON Payments.PaymentCurrencyKey = Sales.CurrencyKey
```

> In your First Procedure...Do not assign default value.... For E.g. if
>   you enter only @FromDate only then it will automatically pick last
>   date from your table....
>
> Ex. Your table contain date range from 10 to 30 ... then if you enter
>   15 then..it will automatically select 15 to 30 date range data...and
>   vise-versa For @ToDate also...

**Note:--You can try this all Query...null part is also Handle in Custom Date Range.....**